# Select rows from 2 tables where the first 5 rows come from one table then 1 from the second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables in an SQL database.

```
SELECT name from table1 ORDER BY name
SELECT name from table2 ORDER BY name
```

I want to create a stored procedure with a union select that creates one table with following output - five rows from table1 and one row from table2, then 5 rows from table1 and one row from table2 etc:

```
row 1 from table1
row 2 from table1
row 3 from table1
row 4 from table1
row 5 from table1
row 6 from table2
row 7 from table1
row 8 from table1
row 9 from table1
row 10 from table1
row 11 from table1
row 12 from table2
etc
```

Is that possible? If yes any hints? 
Thanks

Comment: Why not just have two cursors in your stored procedure?

Comment: can you share table model and sample data from t1 and t2? How can you know which row is #1 or #5 in a table and based on what are they ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` and some math:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT name,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) + ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) - 1) / 5)
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) * 6
    FROM table2
)
SELECT name FROM Cte ORDER BY rn
```

The above will display 5 rows from `table` followed by 1 row from `table2`, and so on.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b5d43/1/0)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It sounds feasible to me so I'll test it and keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like this:

```
Select x='1', n, n%5,  id, name From (
    Select id, name 
        , n = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by ID)        
    From T1
) as Q1
Where (n % 6) <> 0
Union All
Select '2', n, n%5, id, name From (
    Select id, name 
        , n = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by ID)        
    From T2
) as Q2
Where (n % 6) = 0
Order By id
```

If your tables already have order ids with no gaps, you most likely don't need to use ROW_NUMBER() to create ordered ids.

You can look at this sample: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3aa3/3/0)

Using Modulo 6 (%6), you will get values from 0 to 6 => 6%6 = 12%6 = 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary table (or add a column) for both tables with a column called for sample "GroupId INT".

```
create #temp ( groupId int, tbl int, name nvarchar(...))
```

For table1, fill this column with CONVERT(INT, ROW_NUMBER() / 5)
For table2, fill this column with ROW_NUMBER()

```
insert into #temp ( groupId, tbl, name)
  select CONVERT(INT, ROW_NUMBER() / 5.0), 1, name from table1 order by name

insert into #temp ( groupId, tbl, name)
  select ROW_NUMBER(), 2, name from table2 order by name
```

Then use

```
SELECT name 
from #temp    
ORDER BY groupId, tbl, name
```

NB: Use of a temporary table can be avoid using CTE I think